# Convert values from a single cell into a matrix

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a small script that allows the user the ability to create a new matrix (10x8) from scratch, that will later be used in bi-linear interpolation.

Currently my method for doing this is using the `prompt` function with 10 rows within the pop-up block. The user would then input the 8 values for each row that they would like. 
This would output a 10x1 cell with the values within. Then this 10x1 cell needs to convert to a 10x8 matrix

Below is a simplified example (5x3) matrix idea with my current code.

User enters;

[image: User Data Input]

Once the data has been entered I've tried to get Matlab to convert those numbers into, in this example, a 5x3 matrix, such as

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

1 5 9

7 5 3

using this code

```
prompt = {'Enter the first row values','Enter the second row values','Enter the third row values'...
           'Enter the forth row values', 'Enter the fifth row values'}%, 'Entre the sixth row values'...
         %'Enter the seventh row values', 'Enter the eighth row values', 'Enter the nineth row values' ...
         %'Enter the tenth row values'};
     title = ' bi-linear interpolation grid ';
     dims = [1 50]; 

answer = inputdlg(prompt,title,dims); 

bi_linear_interpolation_grid = cell2mat(answer);
```

However this creates a 5x5? Char with the values in. Image below

[image: Matlab Result]

I have also tried to use`str2double` as well, another method that has been previously used online, that didn't work at all.

I understand that this may not be the most efficient method for entering data (I am fairly new to Matlab), but I found that this way was a quick and clean method. If you know a simpler way please point me in the right direction

Thank you very much for any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `split()` function:

```
answer = {'1 2 3' ; '4 5 6' ; '7 8 9' ; '10 11 12' ; '13 14 15'};
answer = str2double(split(answer))
```

> answer =
>
> ```
>  1     2     3
>  4     5     6
>  7     8     9
> 10    11    12
> ```

As for the simpler way to input the data, I like to copy and paste directly from Excel to the Variables panel in the workspace. Remember that to paste from Excel to Matlab you should use CTRL + SHIFT + V instead of standard CTRL + V.

Comment: you my friend are very helpful. Thank you